# Calling textField:shouldReplaceCharactersInRange from a delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

I've built a custom on-screen keyboard where each key tap returns a `String?`. In my delegate method, I want to forward that text onto the `UITextFieldDelegate` method: `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

```
func valueWasSent(string: String?) {
    // activeTextField is a UITextField?
    guard let textField = activeTextField else { return }

    let range = NSMakeRange(0, string!.count - 1)
    textField(activeTextField!, shouldChangeCharactersIn: range, replacementString: string!)
}
```

The last line here isn't working, and throwing the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITextField'

Any idea how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you should not be calling that delegate method yourself. The `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is simply a check if the edit would be valid. Normally, `UITextField` calls it to ensure the proposed change will be valid or not. If not, the change is ignored. If so, then the text field's text is updated.

If you really do want to call it, then you need to call it on the delegate, not `self`. You need to check the return value. If it returns `true` then you should update the text field's text accordingly.

```
if textField.delegate?.textField(textField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: range, replacementString: string!) {
    // update the text field's text
}
```

Also note that the range you pass to it should reflect the current selection in the text field. You are setting it to match the length of `string`. That's bad. If you want `string` to fully replace the current value, at least pass in a range that matches the current value of the text field, not of `string`.

Comment: can you explain this more: "If you really do want to call it, then you need to call it on the delegate, not self."

Comment: Ideally, the custom keyboard delegate method lets `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` make the decision about the edit. But I'm not sure how to make that happen

Comment: Ah thank you! Is there a way now to have the textField's text update without me explicitly setting textField.text? For example, if you're using a hardware keyboard, the value just updates after `shouldChangeCharactersIn` returns true

Comment: Look at the methods of the `UITextInput` and `UIKeyInput` protocols (which `UITextField` conforms to).